# Using a dropdown list or radio buttons to give meaningful rules on a webform

Tags: forms, gui-design, ux-field, radio-buttons, drop-down-list

I have a situation where user based on user dropdown value selection , below control either show radio button choice or multiple select option. How to handle this kind of scenario for better user experience control level.[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Does the dropdown for Option A have between 2 - 5 selections?**

One advantage of radio buttons is that all choices are visible to the user.

You could use radio buttons for the first choice, then use the **expose within** pattern for the available subitems for Item1 and Item2.

LukeW discusses this pattern in his insightful book **[Web Form Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933820241)** (page 186).

Here's an *expose within* example from Codepen, where content is exposed depending on which choice you make:

[image]

#### When to use either radio buttons or checklists for your subchoices.

I'm not sure if you're also asking about the subchoices, but here's a few guidelines for when to use which control.

According to the **[Mac OS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/buttons/radio-buttons)**

**For Radio Buttons:**

> Radio buttons are typically presented in groups of between two and five to provide the user with a set of mutually exclusive but related choices. A radio button’s state is either on (a filled circle) or off (an empty circle).

**For Checkboxes:**

> Use a set of checkboxes when the user needs the ability to select multiple options at the same time. Except in a rare case where a mixed state is needed, radio buttons should be mutually exclusive.